# switching block focus in cuda-cdb

Tags: gdb, cuda

Pretty simple... I want to change focus in cuda-gdb. I can change to a different thread within the current block (block 0), but not to a different block. I'm using cuda/cuda-gdb 3.0

The way in the 3.0 manual:

> ```
> (cuda-gdb) cuda block
> Current CUDA focus: block (0,0).
> (cuda-gdb) cuda block (9,0)
> CUDA focus unchanged.
> (cuda-gdb) cuda thread (9,0,0)
> New CUDA focus: device 0, sm 1, warp 0, lane 9, grid 42672, block (0,0), thread (9,0,0).
> ```

or the other way (from the 3.2 manual):

> ```
> (cuda-gdb) thread
> [Current Thread 2 (Thread 140272898447104 (LWP 28681))]
> [Current CUDA Thread <<<(0,0),(0,0,0)>>>]
>
> (cuda-gdb) thread <<<(9),(10)>>>
> Switching to <<<(9,0),(10,0,0)>>> 0x000000000246a5c8 in my_kernel
>     <<<(16,1),(128,1,1)>>> ...
>
> (cuda-gdb) thread
> [Current Thread 2 (Thread 140272898447104 (LWP 28681))]
> [Current CUDA Thread <<<(0,0),(0,0,0)>>>]
>
> (cuda-gdb) thread <<<20>>>
> Switching to <<<(0,0),(20,0,0)>>> 0x000000000246a5c8 in my_kernel
>     <<<(16,1),(128,1,1)>>> ...
>
> (cuda-gdb) thread
> [Current Thread 2 (Thread 140272898447104 (LWP 28681))]
> [Current CUDA Thread <<<(0,0),(20,0,0)>>>]
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

---

cuda 3.0 | ubuntu 9.04 | gtx 480

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `info cuda sm` (IIRC) you can see the currently active blocks. It's not possible to switch to a block (or a warp within a block) that has already completed execution.

If you want to look at a specific block then you should be able to break on the kernel function itself, then change focus, then continue the debugging session.